# Modified exponential distribution in R

Tags: r, probability

I would like to make my own probability density function in R to simulate some things from a paper.

It is somehow similar to exponential distribution but what i really want to do is to redefine the exponential distribution into a "modified" one...

Is there such a way to do this? Thanks.

---

I want to simulate this:

b(x) = {(µ/p)(e ^ (-(µx-q)/p) , x > q(xbar) and 0 otherwise  }

xbar is an x with a line above it, mean, average

Comment: there certainly is: define a function called `rmodexp` (or some such). However, random deviate generation is not always easy -- fairly minor modifications in a distribution can make it much harder to simulate, or to simulate efficiently.  If you tell us exactly what you want (i.e. what is the density function or cumulative density function of the modified function you are after?) someone will probably help ...

Comment: Would this be better suited for http://stats.stackexchange.com?

Comment: I don't have time to work this out fully, but this looks like a scaled and shifted exponential.  I don't fully understand the notation, but ... I suspect that `mu/p*rexp(n)+q/p` will get you most of the way there. Can you give a reference to the paper itself?

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware that exponential distributions truncated from below remain exponential distributions?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do what you want with `?sample` .  Use your known distribution function `b(x)` to generate a vector of probabilities, say `bprob` , then

```
sample(x,size, replace=TRUE,prob=bprob)
```

There are some very interesting methods for generating samples from arbitrary distributions.  See for example, Normal RandomNumbers:UsingMachine AnalysisTo Choosethe BestAlgorithm
W. H. PAYNE WashlngtonState University  (somewhere on the web), or Numerical Recipes in C
The Art of Scientific Computing Second Edition
William H. Press,Saul A. Teukolsky et al, chapter 7.3